# "System" command in c giving wrong output with pipes of bash

Tags: c, bash, pipe

I am trying to understand the internal working of pipes in C. I noticed if I run

```
int main() { 
    system("ls | grep d | wc");                        
}
```

Output:

```
3       3      53
```

But on running the same command with bash I get

```
3       3      104
```

Output of ls | grep d

question_1.pdf
question_2.pdf
question_2_dataset.txt

Can someone explain the cause of this discrepancy?
The same thing occurs if I use pipe via `pipe()` call in C.

Comment: Get rid of the `wc`. What is the output of `ls | grep d` in the two cases?

Comment: ls is often an alias in an interactive shell. What does `command ls |grep d | wc` do ?

Comment: Is the current working directory the same for your program's subsystem shell and your terminal shel?

Comment: What's the output from `\ls | grep d | wc` when typed from the command line?  How about the output from `alias | grep ls` from the command line?

Comment: @Cornstalks yes same directory

Comment: @AndrewHenle alias ls='ls -G' is output of second command and first one gives 3 3 104

Comment: @PSkocik, `system()` is starting a new copy of `sh`; it's not going to be interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured out problem wasn't with ls but "grep --color=always d" which is alias of grep in my bash. The colored characters have extra length which increase the length of output.

Comment: `system()` doesn't start bash, it starts a new noninteractive `sh` (without any aliases defined) -- or do you mean you were *comparing against* results from bash?

Comment: yeah I was comparing against bash result

Answer (score 0):

Check out what your 'ls' command at the bash is! Try:

> type ls

You probably will find that `ls` is an alias of some kind.

Check your bash-test again with

> /bin/ls | grep d | wc

If you then get th esame result as in your C-Code you will know what went wrong.

Comment: It is 3       3      104. The character count is 53 only. Why 104 from /bin/ls ?

Comment: ls is aliased to `ls -G'
is output of "type ls"

Answer (score 0):

ls is often an alias in an interactive shell.
For example, in my bash session if I do `type ls` I get

```
ls is aliased to `ls -t --group-directories-first  -I .pyc -I __pycache__ -I .git  --color=auto -xF'
```

(The alias usually comes from $`HOME/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`).

Now if you do:

```
sh -c 'ls | grep d | wc'
```

(or `command ls| command grep d | command wc` ) you should get absolutely the same result as with compiling

```
int main() { system("ls | grep d | wc"); }
```

and running it in the same directory.

Comment: The output of  sh -c 'ls | grep d | wc'  is same as system("ls|grep d|wc") but when I check alias for 'ls' in my .bashrc and .bash_profile it is aliased to "ls -G" where G is for colorized output only. I can't figure out from where exactly this  difference is coming

Comment: @MeghaAgarwal There's multiple shell config files. Better try to query your interactive shell directly, with either `alias ls` or `type ls` to see what it really is. The other commands may be aliases too. Play with it. Try modifying the pipeline (e.g., remove the |wc part) and see what's going on. Interaction is what interactive shells rock at.